# Querying SQL Server tables while they are locked

Tags: sql-server, transactions, entity-framework-6, sqlbulkcopy, transaction-isolation

I have two DBs on Azure let's say `DBLive` and `DBCrud`.

`DBLive` contains the tables that provide the real data. There is one table for which the CRUD operations are not done on `DBLive` but on `DBCrud`. The table structure is replicated on `DBCrud` - so after doing our CRUD operations on `DBCrud` we do a synchronization to `DBLive` by doing a SQLbulkcopy.

Given there many records, the bulkcopy takes time. During this time the app must still provide users with data (A `SELECT` Query EF6 let's call it STATUSQUERY) from `DBLive` even if dirty - even if they look like before the bulkcopy was initiated. But given the synchronization process the query hangs and timeout.

Initially I used SQlbulkCopyOptions.TableLock , then used an external transaction with IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted. This still does not solve the problem. The select query still hangs. I cannot use `IsolationLevel.Snapshot` because of DBA policy.

Comment: Languages, spoken and code, are best written with formatting. That block of text is *very* difficult to read.

Comment: Set BulkCopy batch size with an internal transaction? Although that means you cannot rollback in case of error